# AWS Lightsail automatic backup shell script

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, backup, snapshot, amazon-lightsail

I have got a script for creating automatic lightsail snapshots(backup) through EC2 and it works fine, but how can I add more than one lightsail instances in a same script? The Script is as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
aws lightsail create-instance-snapshot --instance-name Ubuntu-512MB-Virginia-1 --instance-snapshot-name $(date +%Y-%m-%d) --profile lightsail_backup_test --region us-east-1
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you can simply add another call?

```
#!/bin/bash
ts=$(date +%Y-%m-%d)

aws lightsail create-instance-snapshot --instance-name Ubuntu-512MB-Virginia-1 --instance-snapshot-name "Ubuntu-512MB-$ts" --profile lightsail_backup_test --region us-east-1

aws lightsail create-instance-snapshot --instance-name Ubuntu-2 --instance-snapshot-name "Ubuntu-2-$ts" --profile lightsail_backup_test --region us-east-1
```